# How to read a file from the specified location and to convert to stream in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, filestream

I have tried the below code to access a file from the location and convert it into stream

```
 string filename = @"D:\ShapeFiles\usa_state.shp";

 FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Getting file not found exception, but file exists in that location.

Comment: your mobile app can't read a file from your local desktop.  It can only read files from its own local storage.

Comment: Is it possible to access the file from the common location to all Android, iOS, UWP platform. But I don't want to add in the application as embedded resource.

Comment: The only "common location" is to embed it in the app package somehow - as a resource, asset, etc, or to download it from some external source at runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the file
var path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "usa_state.shp");
var stream = File.OpenRead(path);
```